# Do we need to use an updater function here?

Tags: reactjs

This is the code snippet from one of the taks in react documentation. Is it correct to update the state of lastCoordinates this way and use it right away? It seems to me that it is better to use an updater function like this `setLastCoordinates(() => {x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY})`, isn't it?

```
  const [
    lastCoordinates,
    setLastCoordinates
  ] = useState(null);

  function handlePointerMove(e) {
    if (lastCoordinates) {
      setLastCoordinates({
        x: e.clientX,
        y: e.clientY,
      });
      const dx = e.clientX - lastCoordinates.x;
      const dy = e.clientY - lastCoordinates.y;
      onMove(dx, dy);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. When you have only one update at the rendering, there is no difference between direct update `setState(newState)` and fuction that returns the new update `setState(() => newState)`
2. When you update the state based on the current state, it's better to use a fuction to reflect the latest ever value `setState(val => ({...val, size: val.size + 1}))`
3. When you update the state more than once at the same rendering:

```js
doSomeLogic()

setState(...)

doOtherLogic()

serState(...)
```

At this case, it has different behavior when you pass the new value directly verse when updating by function.

If you update the state by a new value (not based on the current state) there is no difference.

```js
doSomeLogic()

setState(1)

doOtherLogic()

serState(2)
```

At the previous snippet, after a re-render the state will have the last update value `2`

When updating the state more than once based on the current state there is a difference behavior:

```js
const [count, setCount]= useState(1)

// ...
setCount(count + 1) // count = 1 ==> 1 + 1
// ...
setCount(count + 1) // count still equal 1 ==> 1 + 1
```

After a re-render you might expect `count` to be `3`, but it's `2`.

Let's now update the state by function:

```js
const [count, setCount]= useState(1)

// ...
setCount((c) => c + 1) // count = 1, c = 1 ==> 1 + 1
// ...
setCount((c) => c + 1) // count still equal 1 but c = 2 ==> 1 + 1
```

After the re-render, `count` will be `3`.

In the snippet included in the question, there is no difference between the two ways. Because you're not update based on the current state but update by a completely new value.

Both ways are correct:

```js
setLastCoordinates({
  x: e.clientX,
  y: e.clientY,
});

// or

setLastCoordinates(()=> ({
  x: e.clientX,
  y: e.clientY,
}));
```